# UITableView inside UINavigationController doesn't scroll

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios4

I've got a MainWindow.xib file:

Inside there I've defined a UINavigationController as rootViewController of the Window.
The UINavigationController has a TableVC - item.

TableVC inherits from UITableViewController and implements the appropriated Delegate and Datasource.

I overwrite 4 methods, viewDidload to initialize data and:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [data count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with this.

When I run the project, the NavigationBar and inside the TableView , populated with my data appears. But I can't scroll the Table!?

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Might I inquire as to why you prefer to show your data as seperate sections of each one row, instead of just one section with seperate rows?

Comment: How is the table view added to your nav controller?

Answer (score 0):

Check out labels:

```
- Scrolling Enabled
- User Interaction Enabled
```

for your tableView in your nib file (using IB of course)

Comment: I've checked it out and, I've got both fields checked.
I did change something there to prevent a warning from appearing.
I've disabled
- Defines Context 
- Privodes Context

Maybe it has got something to do with those settings ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Iv just spotted Warkst's comment and I have realized you have a mistake an your code.  Im not sure if its causing the issue or not but you should fix it.

This line here:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Should be

```
cell.textLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

Since you are using rows not sections.

This would mean you are getting the same data in each row since `indexPath.row` would always be zero.

---

Firstly, I would suggest not using a `UITableViewController`.  Instead add a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController`'s view.  This will make a much more flexible if you need to move the table around later.

Now there are a number of reasons why you might not be scrolling.

1. It thinks it dont need to scroll, i.e. the content size isnt bigger than the frames size.

   I dont think this is it because the table view sort this out itself.  But try logging the frame and the content size just incase.
2. Its not receiving touch events.

   This could be because some other views is hijacking the events.  Try overriding touches began touches ended etc, just log the event and call super.  You will need to make a subclass of UITableView.

   Otherwise there might be a funny view structure.  If its outside of its parent's view frame it wont get touch events.  Try moving the whole thing outside the Navigation view int a clean view to see if that fixes it.
3. Scrolling is disabled.

   Check buy loggin the property on the table view, `scrollEnabled`.

Thats all I can think of for now. let me know how it goes.

Comment: Wrong place, misclick, moved the comment.